# Angularjs getting clean url returns url undefined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to get clean urls using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` gives

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined.
```

The application uses `$stateProvider` for routing.

I also have the base url defined in `<head>`

```
<base href="/">
```

From anglularjs lib:

```
function trimEmptyHash(url) {
  return url.replace(/(#.+)|#$/, '$1');
}
```

url passed to this function is empty. Anyone knows a workaround.
This is my app config:

```
wgApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')

  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: "/main",
      cache: false,
      templateUrl: "/web-master/main.html"
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "/web-master/main.html"
    })

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
 })
```

Comment: share relevant code please

Comment: Workaround for what? `url passed to this function is empty` doesn't make sense. Have you configured server for html5Mode?

Comment: @NitsanBaleli I have put my config code. If i remove html5Mode(true), it will work fine with # in every url

Comment: $locationProvider is supposed to pass the baseUrl to trimEmptyHash(url), but url is undefined. This is my url http://localhost:3000/c/login

Comment: and this is the url i get if i dont user html5Mode http://localhost:3000/c/login#/login $location.baseUrl() is returning undefined